# JavaFX custom component with custom controller

Tags: java, javafx, controller

I try to make a custom component with a custom controller. The custom component is already shown on the application, but I fail to add properties to it.

**Project Structure:**

- Main.class           --> Displays the Application Window
- TopBarBtn.class      --> Custom controller
- TopBarCloseBtn.class  --> Custom component
- closeBtn.fxml         --> Style for the custom component

**The custom-controller (TopBarBtn.class):**

```
package controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class TopBarBtn implements Initializable {

    public ImageView getIv() {
        return iv;
    }

    public HBox getHbox() {
        return hbox;
    }

    @FXML private ImageView iv;

    @FXML private HBox hbox;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        
    }
}
```

**My component (TopBarCloseBtn.class):**

```
package custom;

import controller.TopBarBtn;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TopBarCloseBtn extends HBox {
    TopBarBtn controller;
    private final StringProperty imageUrl = new SimpleStringProperty("/res/image/white/closeX.png");

    public final StringProperty imageUrl() { return imageUrl; }

    public final String getImageUrl() { return imageUrl.get(); }

    public final void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
                                               this.imageUrl.set(imageUrl);
                                               controller.getIv().setImage(new Image(imageUrl));
                                           }

    public TopBarCloseBtn() {
        super();
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/res/template/closeBtn.fxml"));
            controller = new TopBarBtn();
            loader.setController(controller);
            Node n = loader.load();
            this.getChildren().add(n);
            controller.getIv().setImage(new Image(imageUrl.get()));
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

**closeBtn.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<HBox id="hbox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="27" prefWidth="40"
      styleClass="TopBarButtonClose" stylesheets="@../style/TopBarButton.css">
    <children>
        <ImageView id="iv" fitHeight="13" fitWidth="13" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="/res/image/white/closeX.png"/>
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</HBox>
```

The problem I face is, that the line `controller.getIv().setImage(new Image(imageUrl.get()));` in my component class raise a NullPointerException (full error at the end), because all variables in my custom controller are not initialized. I thought that the @FXML annotation indicates a field that should be initialized by the FXMLLoader to reference objects created corresponding to elements in an FXML file when the FXML file is loaded.
So I don't see my mistake here, can you help me there?
Please feel also free to correct some things, these are my first steps with JavaFX.

BR
Marco

Full error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "javafx.scene.image.ImageView.setImage(javafx.scene.image.Image)"
> because the return value of "controller.TopBarBtn.getIv()" is null    at
> custom.TopBarCloseBtn.(TopBarCloseBtn.java:33)  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:642)    at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1021)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:756)
> at
> javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
> at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
> ... 17 more

Comment: missing fx:id in fxml

Comment: Note for future questions: It's much easier to read stack traces when they're formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

Missing fx:id in my closeBtn.fxml!
Thanks to @kleopatra